# Galerkin Method

Tags: partial-differential-equations, finite-element-method, galerkin-methods

Can someone please explain this to me, the part where we take the integrals, why is it not $ \frac{1}{ \Delta x^{2}} $  for K11  how do they get 2\deltax >?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The basis functions are supported on very small intervals, so while both of them contribute a $\frac{1}{\Delta x}$, the length of the interval is only $\Delta x$ so we end up with an interval on the order of $$\frac{1}{\Delta x^2} \Delta x = \frac{1}{\Delta x}$$

Comment: so where di they 2 come from ? I am just learnig this method and am still very confused.

Comment: You can explicitly do the integrals to see exactly where everything comes from. The actual support of each basis function has length $2\Delta x$ which is why there is a two. The support of adjacent functions overlap on intervals of length $\Delta x$.

Comment: I see it now thank you